# Cannot pass data from one page to another using useState on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I am running a function when the user clicks a button, this function updates my `useState` and adds an array into it as data. This data later on is passed into another webpage where the array objects are displayed in a different way. I'm running into an issue where, my `useState` is not updating and instead returns an empty array. I suspect it has something to do with the new page refreshing and not updating the `useState`. I am just not sure where to go from here.

I am using React-Router V6 for this

Here is my Parent webpage along with the button.

```
<div className="toggleButtons" key={id}>
  <Link
    to={"/DetailsPage"}
    onClick={toggledItem}
    state={{ data: data }}
    className="primary-ff boxyButton"
  >
    {buttonText}
  </Link>

  <a href={link} className="icon-link" target="_blank">
    <i className="fa-solid fa-arrow-up-right-from-square"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Here is where I am trying to pass an array list into my `useState`

```js
const softiesInfo = pageContentList.find(({id}) => id == 1);
const palcoInfo = pageContentList.find(({id}) => id == 2);
const tlaxInfo = pageContentList.find(({id}) => id == 3);

const [data, setData] = useState({})

const toggledItem = () => {
  if (id === 1) {
    setData(softiesInfo);
  } else if (id === 2) {
    setData(palcoInfo)
  } else {
    setData(tlaxInfo)
  }
};
```

Here is where my data should be rendered on my second page.

```
export default function DetailsPage() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const data = location.state;
  return (
    <div className="header-wrap">
      <h1 className="primary-ff">{data.title}</h1>
      <img src={data.logoImg} alt={data.altLogo} />
    </div>
  )
});
```

I tried force feeding the data into my `useState` like this and this resulted successful, but I don't see it being very efficient and would count as writing clean code.

```js
const [data, setData] = useState({
  sectionName: "softies-section",
  title: "Softies Ice Cream-Under The Scoop",
  logoImg: softieslogo,
  altLogo: "softies-logo",
  img: softiesPlanner,
  altImg: "Career Day At Pinnacle",
  img2: softiesAccordion,
  constrainContent:
    "lorem a;sdkfj;alskdjfa lksdfjlaksjdl;fkjasldk;fjaslkdfjal;sdkjfalksdjf;laks;dj asflsngealj    sflsdajflkads",
  id: 1,
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is that the `Link` component effects a navigation action *immediately* when it is clicked, and the passed `state` prop will include whatever the `data` value is ***at the time*** the link is clicked.

The `DetailsPage` also isn't accessing into the passed state reference the `data` property, it's only declaring a local variable named `data` and setting it to the value of `location.state`. `DetailsPage` would need to access `data.data.title` to get the passed information.

## Solution

You can prevent the default link action from happening and effect the navigation action manually later. Unfortunately because enqueued React state updates are processed asynchronously you also can't use the `data` state in the route state. What you *can* do however is to enqueue the state update alongside the imperative navigation action with the same value.

Example:

```js
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const navigate = useNavigate();

...

const toggledItem = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); // <-- prevent link navigation

  let data = {};

  switch(id) {
    case 1:
      data = softiesInfo;
      break;

    case 2:
      data = palcoInfo;
      break;

    case 3:
    default:
      data = tlaxInfo;
      break;
  }

  setData(data);
  navigate( // <-- imperative navigation
    "/DetailsPage",
    { state: { data } }
  );
};
```

...

```
<Link
  to="/DetailsPage"
  onClick={toggledItem}
  className="primary-ff boxyButton"
>
  {buttonText}
</Link>
```

```
export default function DetailsPage() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { data } = location.state ?? {};

  return (
    <div className="header-wrap">
      <h1 className="primary-ff">{data.title}</h1>
      <img src={data.logoImg} alt={data.altLogo} />
    </div>
  )
});
```

Comment: This seems to actually be passing the information into my other page, however, I am not able to pull these properties from the data constant. I am simply using a {data.title} approach in order to try and pull these objects but see no success and none of them display although the data information is there as my console log shows

Comment: @ang.jr57 I don't understand what you mean by "pull these properties from data constant". Do you mean reading the `data` value to pass in state in the "parent" component, or are you saying that `location.state.data` is not working in the receiving component?

Comment: Yes I did some further debugging and realized that my location.state.data is not working, and seems to be the root of the problem

Comment: @ang.jr57 So is it working now when using `location.state.data` instead of just `location.state` in the `DetailsPage` component? E.G. `const { data } = location.state ?? {};` instead of `const data = location.state;`?

Comment: Yes, I managed to get it to work now, It was most likely something having to do with my data constant, and the way I was using it in order to reference my objects in my JSX. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue you're encountering might be related to passing state via React Router's **Link** component. In React Router v6, the way to pass state via a link has changed compared to previous versions. Instead of using state directly on the **Link** component, you need to use the state prop of the navigate function from the **useNavigate** hook.

Here's how you can update your code to pass state properly:

```
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

// Parent component
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const toggledItem = () => {
    if (id === 1) {
      navigate('/DetailsPage', { state: { data: softiesInfo } });
    } else if (id === 2) {
      navigate('/DetailsPage', { state: { data: palcoInfo } });
    } else {
      navigate('/DetailsPage', { state: { data: tlaxInfo } });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="toggleButtons" key={id}>
      <button onClick={toggledItem} className="primary-ff boxyButton">
        {buttonText}
      </button>
      <a href={link} className="icon-link" target="_blank">
        <i className="fa-solid fa-arrow-up-right-from-square"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};

// DetailsPage component
const DetailsPage = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { data } = location.state || {}; // Ensure data is properly destructured with a default value

  return (
    <div className="header-wrap">
      <h1 className="primary-ff">{data?.title}</h1>
      <img src={data?.logoImg} alt={data?.altLogo} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Make sure you have imported `useNavigate` from **'react-router-dom'**. With this approach, **state** will be properly passed to the destination page via the ***React Router navigation mechanism***.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your feedback, will test my code when I get the chance, and will get back with you here, thanks again.